# JavaのPDFBoxライブラリを使用して、日本語を含むサイズの小さなPDFを生成したい

Tags: java, pdf, font

Java + PDFBoxで、なるべくファイルサイズが小さくなるように日本語を含むPDFを生成するにはどうすればよいでしょうか。

日本語のフォントサイズは大きいので、できればファイルに埋め込みたくはないのですが、どのようにしたらいいでしょうか。iTextでは、バンドルされている小塚明朝などを使用して、フォントを埋め込まずに日本語出力ができます。しかし、iTextにはライセンスの問題があるため、PDFBoxを使用したい状況です。

以下のコードでサブセット埋め込みを試みたのですが、`PDType0Font.load()`関数の第3引数（サブセット埋め込みをbooleanで指定するもの）を`true`にするとエラーになってしまいます。

```
PDDocument pdDoc;
        //For ver3.0.1
        //pdDoc = Loader.loadPDF(new File(pdffile));
        //For ver2.x.x
        pdDoc = PDDocument.load(new File(pdffile));

        //TsukuhouMincho is free Japanese font. If I set true to embedSubset argument, it generates error.

        PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(pdDoc, PDFBOXTester.class.getResourceAsStream("/font/TsukuhouMincho-Regular.ttf"), false);
        

        PDDocumentCatalog pdCatalog = pdDoc.getDocumentCatalog();
        PDAcroForm pdAcroForm = pdCatalog.getAcroForm();
        PDTextField textfield = (PDTextField) pdAcroForm.getField("Text_TaxOffice_JP");

        PDResources res = pdAcroForm.getDefaultResources();
        String fontName = res.add(font).getName();
        textfield.setDefaultAppearance("/" + fontName + " 0 Tf 0 g");
        textfield.setValue(someJapanaeseStrings);
        
        pdDoc.save(new File(args[1]));
```

`PDType0Font.load()`の第3引数を`true`にすると表示されるエラーメッセージ：

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No glyph for U+65E5 (日) in font TsukuhouMincho-Regular at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2.encode(PDCIDFontType2.java:389) at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font.encode(PDType0Font.java:427) at
```

Comment: PDFにフォントを埋め込まない場合、通常そのファイルが開かれた際には開いた環境にあるフォントで表示がなされると思います。iTextの出力PDFはフォントを埋め込まないということなので、この状態でしょうか。結局、この質問の趣旨は「PDFBoxでフォントのサブセットを埋め込みたい」なのか「フォントを埋め込むか否かはどちらでもよく、意図通りの文字が表示されればよい」のかどちらなのでしょうか？

Comment: 目的があいまいな表現になってしまい失礼しました。一番の目的は、出力されたファイルサイズを小さくすることです。したがって、iText のように、日本語フォントを埋め込まずにユーザPC環境の日本語フォントを利用する方法がベストです。PDFBOXでそれが実現できればよいのですが、できないのであれば、サブセット埋め込みをしてファイルサイズを小さくしたいと考えています。

Comment: なるほど、いちばん重要な目的は「ファイルを小さくしたい」ということはわかりました。ところで、質問中のコードは何を目指した（一切埋め込まないことを目指した or サブセットの埋め込みを目指した）ものでしょうか。また、エラーメッセージと質問の関係は何でしょうか？

Comment: 質問の中のコードは、サブセット埋め込みをしようとしています。エラーメッセージは、上記のコードを実行した際に、embedSubset 引数をtrue にすると、発生するエラーになります。この引数をfalseにすると、動きますがフォント全体が埋め込まれてしまいます。そのため、このエラーの解決方法を探しております。

Comment: いろいろ明確にしていただきありがとうございます。質問を編集して反映させておきました（なにか事実誤認になっていたら修正してください）。エラーを見る限り「U+65E5 (日)に対応する文字がない」ことが問題になっています。まずフォントTsukuhouMincho-Regularに文字U+65E5 (日)が収録されているか確認する必要があると思います。収録されているのにエラーとなっているのであれば、フォントエンコーディング等の指定が間違っている疑いがあると思います。

Comment: あとは、動作確認できていませんが「あえて和文フォントを一切埋め込まない」のであれば日本語グリフを含まないフォントをPDType0Font.load()に指定するとよいという情報を見かけました。仮に、お手許にある適当な英文フォント（よく使われるHelvetica等）を指定したらどうなるのでしょうか？

Comment: 色々とアドバイスありがとうございます。”TsukuhouMincho-Regularに文字U+65E5 (日)が収録されているかどうか”の点につきましては、embedSubset をfalse にしますと、正しく日本語が出力されますので、含まれているという認識です。”英文フォントを指定する”という点につきまして、日本語出力が必須であるため、こちらは採用できない状況となっております。

Comment: いや、英文フォントを使用すると日本語文字のグリフは当然ないので「日本語部分についてはフォント埋め込みのないPDF」が生成されないかなということです。`PDType0Font.load()`の第3引数をtrueにしたら多分今と同じようなエラーが出るでしょうが、falseだと日本語フォントの埋め込みなし（システムフォントで表示される）の軽いPDFが生成されないのかな、と。

Comment: 失礼しました。Arial.ttf を指定してみたところ、引数はtrue/false に関わらず、下記のエラーがでてしまいました。java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No glyph for U+65E5 (日) in font ArialMT

Comment: その後、自己解決しましたので共有させていただきます。結論としては、事前にフォントをサーバOS（当方の環境はLinuxサーバ）にインストールされた状態であれば、embedSubset引数をtrueにすることで、フォントを全く埋め込まれないPDFが作成できました。（ちなみに、iTextでは小塚明朝を使用する場合、フォントをOSにインストールする必要はありません。）また、作成されたPDFを見る際に、基本的にクライアント側でもフォントを事前にインストールする必要があります。iTextで作成した場合は、代替フォントで表示されるようなのですが、PDFBOXの場合、フォントがインストールされていないとEncoding の問題なのか文字化けしてしまいました。

Comment: 解決したようで何よりです。結局、あまりお役に立てずすみませんでした。このコメントの内容のほぼそのままでもよいので、[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)しておくとよいと思います。48時間待てば自分で自分の回答を承認することも可能です。

Comment: 色々とアドバイスいただき感謝しております。自己回答いたしました。

Answer (score 3):

その後、自己解決しましたので共有させていただきます。

結論としては、事前にフォントがサーバOS（当方の環境はLinuxサーバ）にインストールされた状態であれば、embedSubset引数をtrueにすることで、フォントを全く埋め込まれないPDFが作成できました。（ちなみに、iTextでは小塚明朝を使用する場合、フォントをOSにインストールする必要はありません。）

また、作成されたPDFを見る際に、基本的にクライアント側でもフォントを事前にインストールする必要があります。iTextで作成した場合は、代替フォントで表示されるようなのですが、PDFBOXの場合、フォントがインストールされていないとEncoding の問題なのか文字化けしてしまいました。

Answer (score -2):

DFBoxのフォント関連の処理において、サブセット埋め込みがうまくいかない場合、以下のアプローチを試してみることができます。

フォントの変更: 別の日本語フォントを試してみてください。フォントによっては、埋め込まずに正常に動作することがあります。いくつかのフリーフォントやシステムに既にインストールされているフォントなど、異なるフォントを試してみることを検討してください。

java
Copy code
// 別の日本語フォントを試す
PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(pdDoc, PDFBOXTester.class.getResourceAsStream("/font/AnotherJapaneseFont.ttf"), false);
iTextのAsian Fontを利用: iTextには、Asian Fontとして知られる特定のアジア言語用のフォントが含まれています。これをPDFBoxで使用することで、ライセンスの問題を回避しつつ、適切なフォントを利用できるかもしれません。
java
Copy code
PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(pdDoc, PDFBOXTester.class.getResourceAsStream("/font/iTextAsianFont.ttf"), false);

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。異なるフォントを試してみましたが、同じ状況です。具体的なフォントを教えていただけるとありがたいです。また、iTextには、ttfフォントは含まれていないようでした。